# How to get express's json response in promise catcher?

Tags: node.js, express, promise, axios

I have this express router.

```
app.get('/is-unique-email', function(req, res){

   // if email address is unique 
   if(unique){
       res.json({ unique: true })
       return
   } 

   // else return 403 with error message 
   res.status(403).json({
          email: 'Email already taken.'
   })
})
```

Then how to use above json with axios ?

```
    axios.get('/is-unique-email', { email })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

No problem with normal 200 response, I can get response data like this :

```
{data: { unique: true }, status: 200, ... }
```

But 403 response, I got this response :

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

**What I really want is**

```
{ status: 403, error : error, email: 'email already taken' }
```

How can I get 403 response with JSON format? I'm newbie developer, building json api server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response data is stored inside `err.response`

So you would do:

```
axios.get('/is-unique-email', { email })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.response)
        })
```